# Is Google cloud platform Vmware engine VMs able to use GCP HTTP load balancer as frontend?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am wondering if when you use the new GCP VMware engine product in order to have Vmware Vms colocated on GCP datacenters, you are then able to use services as GCP HTTP load balancer, cloud Armor & CDN as a frontend with the Vmware engine vms being the backend of the HTTP load balancer.

The documentation on GCP does not cover this topic, and it seems that the VMware engine network, firewall, vpn etc is somehow different than the usual GCP VPC network. That's why I am wondering if the Vmware vms can be reached from the outside the same way as GCE instances.

Answer (score 1):

Currently VMWare Backends are not supported by GCP Load Balancers, please view this [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service) to view supported backends. However, you may create a feature request for this use case, you can do so by following the provided [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187245&template=1162973). Please include in detail how you would like to see this work.